# ADO and Microsoft SQL database backup and archival

Tags: c#, c++, sql-server, database-design, ado

I am working on re-engineering/upgrade of a tool. The database communication is in C++(unmanaged ADO) and connects to SQL server 2005.

I had a few queries regarding archiving and backup/restore techniques.

1. Generally archiving is different than backup/restore . can someone provide any link which explains me that .Presently the solution uses bcp tool for archival.I see lot of dependency on table names in the code. what are the things i have to consider in choosing the design(considering i have to take up the backup/archival on a button click, database size of 100mb at max)
2. Will moving the entire communication to .net will be of any help? considering lot of ORM tools. also all the bussiness logic and UI is in C#
3. What s the best method to verify the archival data ?

PS: the questionmight be too high level, but i did not get any proper link to understand this. It will be really helpful if someone can answer. I can provide more details!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At 100 MB, I would say you should probably not spend too much time on archiving, and just use traditional backup strategies. The size of your database is so small that archiving would be quite an elaborate operation with very little gain, as the archiving process would typically only be relevant in the case of huge databases.

Generally speaking, a backup in database terms is a way to provide recoverability in case of a disaster (accidental data deletion, server crash, etc). Archiving mostly means you partition your data.

A possible goal with archiving is to keep specific data available for querying, but without the ability to alter it. When dealing with high volume databases, this is an excellent way to increase performance, as read-only data can be indexed much more densely than "hot" data. It also allows you to move the read-only data to an isolated RAID partition that is optimized for READ operations, and will not have to bother with the typical RDBMS IO. Also, by removing the non-active data from the regular database means the size of the data contained in your tables will decrease, which should boost performance of the overall system.

Archiving is typically done for legal reasons. The data in question might not be important for the business anymore, but the IRS or banking rules require it to be available for a certain amount of time.

Using SQL Server, you can archive your data using [partitioning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190787.aspx) strategies. This normally involves figuring out the criteria based on which you will split the data. An example of this could be a date (i.e. data older than 3 years will be moved to the archive-part of the database). In case of huge systems, it might also make sense to split data based on geographical criteria (I.e. Americas on one server, Europe on another).

To answer your questions:

1) See the explanation written above
2) It really depends on what the goal of upgrading is. Moving it to .NET will get the code to be managed, but how important is that for the business?
3) If you do decide to partition, verifying it works could include issuing a query on the original database for data that contains both values before and after the threshold you will be using for partitioning, then splitting the data, and re-issuing the query afterwards to verify it still returns the same record-set. If you configure the system to use an [automatic sliding window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964122%28SQL.90%29.aspx), you could also keep an eye on the system to ensure that data will automatically be moved to the archive partition.

Again, if the 100MB is not a typo, I would think your database is too small to really benefit from archiving. If your goal is to speed things up, put the system on a server that is able to load the whole database into RAM, or use SSD drives.

If you need to establish a data archive for legal or administrative reasons, give horizontal table partitioning a look. It's a pretty straight-forward process that is mostly handled by SQL Server automatically.

Hope this helps you out!

Comment: Thanks for your time and for the reply. It's really good one. I have to read some of these concepts. Some of these are new to me. It was really a good explanation. I will come back to you once i am pretty clear about some of these things!